# PHP: Output data from MySQL columns

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I wanted to get all the rows in a given column and output them, but my code is just not working:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Name,Number FROM Users WHERE Customer_ID = 1);
  if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
  }
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['Name'];
echo $row['Number'];

^ This code is only displaying the first row, how can I list all the rows?
```

Comment: You are missing a " at the end of the first line for starters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop through the rows. Getting the `mysql_fetch_assoc` 1 time, will only return you 1 row (the first one), so you have to do a `mysql_fetch_assoc` for each row in the result. Something like this would do:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    echo $row['Name']." ".$row['Number'];
```

Comment: It worked, however, it's outputting the same data multiple times, although it's stored only in one row

Comment: then please check your query, maybe run it in phpmyadmin or mysql, to see what exactly it returns. the above code should work perfectly if the query is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was from my SQL statment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to display all the rows, you need to use 'while' loop as following:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo $row['Name'];
    echo $row['Number'];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps too. Thanks. Is it possible to tell PHP to fetch identical rows only once? For example, I'm getting 50 'Number: 12345678'.

Comment: Maybe add a `GROUP BY Number` statement to the end of you MySQL query would help.

Comment: You can achieve this by using the keyword 'Distinct' in your query. This will make sure that all the records are unique.